# Where to place the body in a SharePoint Designer workflow POST request

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, designer

I am constructing a REST API call in a SharePoint Designer workflow, to rename a file in a library.

I'm using the *Call HTTP Web Service* action with the POST method, and I've set `this` to the API URL (`https://example.sharepoint.com/_api/web/whatever...`) and `request` contains my request headers (`Content-type: application/json`, amongst others):

[image: Call this HTTP web service]

However, I'm not sure where to put the dictionary that contains my JSON request body. Should it go in the request headers, and if so what should I name it? If not then where should I put it?

Comment: Just a comment for those ones who visit this page because of its title. Unforunately, you are restreicted to dictionaries (that means JSON formatted data in the body) when sending POST requests via the Call HTTP Web Service action of SPD 2013 WFs. If you have a SOAP WS, or some kind of legacy web "API", that requires simple key - value pairs in the POST request body, than you have bad luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Googling 'body' rather than 'payload' (as per my original question title) I found [this blog post](https://rogereriksen.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/create-a-sharepoint-site-using-rest-in-workflow-with-sharepoint-designer/) linked from a MSDN thread.

It says that you need to select **Advanced Properties** from the ribbon, and set the `RequestHeaders` and `RequestContent` options explicitly.